# Forcing the simplification of ratios of radicals

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Mathematica seems to have trouble with expressions like

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} \sqrt{x}$$

Oddly, it doesn't have trouble with

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

which will happily simplify to $1$ even without invoking `Simplify`. I know that usually `FullSimplify` not doing what you expect is because of unconscious assumptions you're not telling Mathematica about, but I'm at a loss as for what value of $x$ I could be talking about where the above two expressions wouldn't be equal...

At any rate, is there any way to force `FullSimplify` to give the expected result (i.e. $1$) in the first of the above cases?

Comment: Test several assumptions and you will find a counterexample: `Grid[Assuming[#, {HoldForm[#], Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[x]} // 
     Simplify] & /@ {x > 0, x >= 0, x <= 0, x < 0}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your requested simplification is not true for negative numbers:

```
Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[x] /. x -> -1
```

> -1

You can give [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) an assumption to get your desired output:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[x], x > 0]
```

> 1

Comment: .... Hm. Okay, so that does in fact work in this specific simplification, but when I tried that in my actual use case, it 'bounced' again. Lemme explore a bit and update my question.

Comment: Okay, so, for more complicated examples with multiple variables, neither `{_>0}` nor (for example) `{m, M}>0` will work. You have to write out in painstaking detail `{m>0,M>0,...}`. I'd like to do that automatically or at least with much less typing; is that new question territory or edit-my-question territory?

Comment: @linkhyrule5 Try `Thread[{m, M}>0]`. Or `Positive[{m, M}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That works. Thanks!